# Any ExtJs treefield ux

Tags: forms, extjs, tree, field, extjs4.1

Is there any ux for using Ext.tree like field in the form?
Something like [Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect](https://github.com/kveeiv/extjs-boxselect) not select but tree.

Comment: Something like [this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ux.TreePicker)?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha documentation includes an example of usage of such selector in their Simple Tasks example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/simple-tasks/index.html?theme=classic 
There they use [Ext.ux.TreePicker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.TreePicker)

Comment: I knew I had seen that in use somewhere.. just couldn't remember where. Well spotted.

Comment: wasn't my question :) I commented above with a link to TreePicker API Docs

Comment: oops :) wasnt paying attention